# Integration with Mathematica or Matlab

Tags: integration, matlab, mathematica

- Assuming $0 < x,y < 1$ and $0<v<1$. Consider the function
  $\,\mathrm{f}\left(x,y\right) = 1 + \left(1 -2x\right)\left(1 - 2y\right)$.
- How to find the integral
  $$
  I \equiv
  \int\left\{\vphantom{\large A}\,
  xy + xy\left(1 - x\right)\left(1 - y\right) \leq v\,\right\}
  \,\mathrm{f}\left(x,y\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
  $$
  using $\texttt{Mathematica}$ or $\texttt{Matlab}$ ?.
- I am trying to show that  $I \leq v$ by this integral for which the integration of $\,\mathrm{f}\left(x,y\right)$ over the region
  $\left\{\vphantom{\large A}\,
  xy + xy\left(1 - x\right)\left(1 - y\right)\leq v\,\right\}$ is essential.

Comment: You shall ask this on mathematica stack exchange, not here.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

$\texttt{Mathematica}$:

```
Clear[f,iverson,v,x,y];

f[x_, y_] := 1 + (1 - 2 x) (1 - 2 y); 
iverson[v_, x_, y_] := If[x y + x y (1 - x) (1 - y) <= v, 1, 0];

Integrate[iverson[v, x, y]f[x, y],{x, 0, 1},{y, 0, 1},
Assumptions -> (0 < v) && (v < 1)]
```

Comment: The integral should be function of $v$ only. But output involves $x$, $y$ and $v$ all.

Comment: @sudhapandey $\mathbf{No}$. Once the integration is performed over $x$ and $y$, it $\texttt{leaves}$ the whole result $\mathbf{as\ a\ function}$ of $v$.

Comment: @ Felix Marin Output is of the form.                                                       2 (v/2 + Integrate[-(1/(-1 + x)^2) - (3 v)/(2 (-1 + x)^2) + Sqrt[(-2 + x)^2 + (4 v (-1 + x))/x]/(2 (-1 + x)^2) - 1/(-1 + x) +Sqrt[(-2 + x)^2 + (4 v (-1 + x))/x]/(2 (-1 + x)) + v/(2 (-1 + x)^2 x) + (3 x)/(-1 + x)^2 + (v x)/(-1 + x)^2 - (
     5 Sqrt[(-2 + x)^2 + (4 v (-1 + x))/x] x)/(4 (-1 + x)^2) + (3 x)/(2 (-1 + x)) - (Sqrt[(-2 + x)^2 + (4 v (-1 + x))/x] x)/( 2 (-1 + x)) - (9 x^2)/(4 (-1 + x)^2) +.....

Comment: @ Felix Marin If you can elaborate the integration I will be thankful to you.

Comment: @sudhapandey Maybe, you didn't include the integration variables. The 'piece' $\texttt{,{x,0,1},{y,0,1},}$

Comment: @sudhapandey My code yields the result as an integration which is a function of $v$:
$$
v + \int_{v}^{1}\frac{v \left(4 x^2-6 x+2\right)-x^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{4 v (x-1)}{x}+(x-2)^2}+x-2\right)}{2 (x-1)^2 x}\,\mathrm{d}x\,,\qquad 0 < v < 1
$$